# Spring @value for system properties giving null

Tags: java, spring, annotations

```
    public class RedisMessageListener implements MessageListener {

        @Value("#{systemProperties['pub']}") 
        private String publisher;

        @Autowired
        private LoadMoedlsFromDB ld;

        @Override
        public void onMessage( final Message message, final byte[] pattern ) {
            System.out.println( "Publisher flag::" + publisher);
            ld.downloadModels();
                if("false".equals(publisher)) {
                System.out.println(message.toString());
                }
        }}
```

This outputs Publisher flag::null

But the same config works in other classes, is this because this is a Redis listener class

Answer (score 0):

The `RedisMessageListener` must be a spring bean. I don't know your spring configuration but if classpath scanning is enabled maybe it is enough to add `@Component` to your class.

Comment: even after putting @Component still the same result, I have classpath scanning is enabled, and the same variable is getting bind properly in other classes, only in this class its a problem since its implementing MessageListener , I am not able to bind any beans in this class

Comment: The interface should not be the problem. But how do you instantiate the RedisMessageListener? You have to get it from the spring context and do not create it with new.

Comment: i was creating new() that was the problem thank  you @Nathanael for pointing out